# Передача файла в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Как в ASP.NET передать файл POST запросом?  (класс, метод)

Comment: Не вижу вашего кода. Где ваши наработки?

Comment: WebForms или MVC?

Comment: @Андрей WebForms

Comment: @AGS17  из сделанного передача содержимого файла POST'ом. не думаю ,что этот код здесь нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/file.pdf")); 
Response.End();
```

Это если файл у вас хранится на сервере. Если файл генерируется на лету, можете его записать прямо в ответ с помощью метода `WriteFile()`.

MSDN:
[TransmitFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.110).aspx),
[WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile(v=vs.110).aspx)