# IIS сервер не отдаёт файл

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

На IIS Express все работает отлично. Переношу на сервер - при попытке скачать файл пишет "Не удалось скачать". Хотя физически он в папке inetpub есть. Права пользователю IUSRS дал полные на папку inetpub

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(model.Date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy h:MM:ss");
string newstring = client.HelloBaza(normalUser, date);

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/"+normalUser+".xlsx"), Convert.FromBase64String(newstring));

string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/" + normalUser + ".xlsx");
byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = normalUser + ".xlsx",
    Inline = true,
};

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return File(filedata, contentType);
```

Comment: Я бы делал так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660116/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-asp-net/660123 Только вместо Transmit - `Response.Write(filedata)`

Comment: Спасибо) помогло

Comment: этот метод - не является методом MVC. Что ещё нужно File - не могу сказать. Возможно Response.Clear поможет.

Comment: Я не досмотрел....вам transfer как раз то что надо.

Comment: *"при попытке скачать файл пишет"* - кто пишет-то? Какие заголовки возвращаются?

Comment: Попробуйте вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрю несколько случаев.

- Кажется не первый раз спрашивают как сгенерировать файл "на лету" приведу пример

  ```
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
   "attachment; filename="+normalUser + ".xlsx");
   Response.Write(filedata); // filedata  - массив байт
   Response.End();
  ```

Список ContentType [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)

- Часто генераторы умеют работать с Stream, тогда запись будет примерно такой

  ```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Например      
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
   "attachment; filename="+normalUser + ".xml");

   dt.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream);
   Response.End();
  ```
- Если нужно передать файл (пробросить с подменой имени или без), то это делается так [Передача файла](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660116/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-asp-net/660123)
- Если нужно просто дать добро на скачивание файлов с определенным разширением с папки, то нужно просто в web.config дописать Copy-обработчик

  ```
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
  <compilation>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".xlsx" 
      type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
  ```

  Разрешение можно дать как для определенного каталога (рекомендуется), так и для всего пула (так проще).

Comment: Вот только прямая работа с Response для MVC-экшена не рекомендуется...

Comment: Согласен. У автора вопроса что-то в коде упущено. Не могу сказать что.