# ASP.NET не находит статический файл(*.p12) при деплое в docker контейнере

Tags: asp.net, docker, google-cloud

В корневой папке проекта у меня расположен файл для подключения к электронным таблицам гугла. Он находится System.IO.File.Exists(keyFilePath) без указания пути, все прекрасно работает при локальном запуске на отладку, при локальном запуске в докер-контейнере. Но при деплое этого приложение в GCloud этот файл уже не может быть найден.

Подскажите, где искать проблему?

Comment: Какое расширение файла, стоит-ли на него ForceCopy Handler ? Пример как xml разрешить скачивать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio/29688263

Comment: ForceCopyHandler это где посмотреть? Я дублировал этот файл в другие папки (wwwroot) - результат тот же. Файл - это ключ для соединения с гугл таблицей - AOXImport-65a1b14a95af.p12

Comment: По идее должно получится по ответу ниже. Если не выходит.... (попадалось что нету доступа как web.config так к ветвям web.config) то самый простой способ - тупо пробросить файл через свой обработчик (заковыристый но можно) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660116/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-asp-net/660123#660123

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого необычного файла нужно в web.config добавлять, что этот файл будет обрабатываться конктретным обработчиком. ForceCopyBuildProvider - обработчик, который отдает копию файла не обрабатывая файл.  Пример обработчика для расширения p12

```
<configuration>...
    <system.web>...
        <compilation>...
            <buildProviders>
                <remove extension=".p12" />
                <add extension=".p12" type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider" />
            </buildProviders>
```

Для .p12 remove делать не обязательно.

Comment: У меня .net core 2.1. Надо ли добавлять web.config?

Comment: Думаю да. Есть и другие способы, можно через оснастку, возможно через код можно... думаю через config проще.

Comment: Что-то ничего не работает. Пробовал ваш вариант с web.config (может его .net core сейчас вовсе игнорирует). Пробовал в файле .csproj добавлять по другим инструкциям. Все равно файл не находит

Comment: Решил наконец-то. добавл вот это - <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Google\AOXImport-65a1b14a95af.p12">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: А... это в проэкт добавить. В диспечере проэкта есть свойства у елемента(файла), и в свойстах есть Always None и ещё одно. Тогда после сборки файл включается в сборку.

Comment: Не могу точно сказать оба аспекта тут нужны, или ли достаточно CopyToOutputDirectory=Always

Comment: Do not copy, Copy always, Copy if newver - эти три есть. Выбрать можно только одно, оно автоматически приписывает разрешения в csproj. У меня проблема была в том, что проект достаточно старый и csproj редактировался вручную другим программистом. Мне пришлось там перепрописывать это(вероятно из каких-то соображений этот файл не включался в итоговый проект, но сейчас без него не все методы работают).

Comment: *без него не все методы работают* - это иллюзия. При "
Do not copy" быстро может обнаружится, что файл не обновляется (сертификат долго действителен - не скоро обнаружится), либо когда будет "чистый" сервак (новый, или страрый переформатируют) то файла не будет. Просто обновлятор не трет файлы, если файл раз "продеплоился" то он не удаляется с сервера.