# Как отправить файл в формате audio/wav или audio/mpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ку, нужно написать api которая на get запрос отправляла ответ в формате Content-Type: audio/wav или audio/mpeg. Ответить на запрос это ладно, но вот как мне вернуть ауди файл, вот тут я встал и не знаю как к этому подступиться. Можете подкинуть ссылку где это описывается  или примерчик. Спасибо

Comment: ключевые слова для поиска в гугле `asp.net response file`, первая ссылка сверху

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660116/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-asp-net

Comment: Вверху есть окно поиска. По c# на SO куча инфы. Например можно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0